# How do I configure mvc-mini-profiler to work with a DbContext that passes the connection string name to the base?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

My DbContext ctor looks like this:

```
public class FnordDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FnordDbContext() : base("Fnord")
    {
    }

    /* stuff */
}
```

And my mvc-mini-profiler bootstrapper looks like this:

```
var sqlConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Fnord"].ConnectionString);
var profiledConnectionFactory = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnectionFactory(sqlConnectionFactory);
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = profiledConnectionFactory;
```

If I remove the connection string in my DbContext ctor, I get profiling as expected. But I don't want to have to name my connection string according to EF's convention. What do I need to change to make mvc-mini-profiler work with my DbContext use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in the a ProfiledDbConnection explicitly to the ctor of your DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(GetProfiledConnection()) {
    }

    private static DbConnection GetProfiledConnection() {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first this didn't work for me. I was getting the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata'" for all querues. Because I'm using migrations, there is no EdmMetadata. To fix this, I had to add: modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>(); to my OnModelCreating. I guess I'll still mark this as an answer. :P

Comment: Using the latest versions of EF and MiniProfiler I had to do this:        public MyDbContext() 
            : base(GetProfiledConnection(), true){
        }

        private static DbConnection GetProfiledConnection()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString;
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            return new ProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
        }